# How can I solve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postgresql, express, localhost

I'm learning to work on PERN. I've created a TODO list app but on connecting it with db and launching the website, it generates the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/app net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Failed to fetch
```

If I use port number other than 5000, it gives ERROR: 404 not found.

Comment: Not sure how Postgresql is involved in this, it looks like the issue is with whatever Web server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Port or host unavailable: Make sure the specified port (in this case 5000) and host (localhost) are accessible and not occupied by other processes or Issues with firewall or security settings: Check to see if your firewall or other security measures are blocking the connection to the specified port and host.